# How to save into a directory each page source in driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, io

How can I create and save into a directory each `driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")`?. For instance, consider the following snippet:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('a_search_box').send_keys('Dog')
driver.find_element_by_id('a_search_box').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

sleep(1)
print("\n",driver.page_source)
driver.back()    
sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

As you can see in the above code, it prints each visited content of `driver`'s object. How can I save into a directory the `page_source` of each website?.

**UPDATE**

I tried to:

```
outfile = open("file_path", "w")
print (outfile, "\n".join(str(i) for i in [driver.page_source]))
outfile.close()
```

Nevertheless, it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import os
import uuid

# your code ...

path = r"/users/me/Documents/websites"

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

buff = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")
filename = "%s_page_grab.htm" % uuid.uuid4()
with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(buff)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Ok, let me check. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yup, files are randomly named

Comment: Sorry, I all ready checked it... How to save them in order (i.e. for each visited site)?... For example assigning them a predefined list of names.

Comment: order files by created time? Windows or Linux? Or include timestamp into the name

Comment: Yes, for example. Let's say I have a list of strings `['file1', ...., 'fileN']`. While each file is time created assign it a name from the pool of strings (i.e. list of strings from `1` to `N`)

Comment: Unix, just a predifined name from the list.

Comment: I did not understood you I got: `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'`

Comment: filenames = ['file1', ...., 'file1000']; old = os.listdir(path); filename = [name for name in filenames if name not in old][0]

Comment: This worked out.. However I got `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: add more filenames filenames = ["file%s" % i for i in xrange(1,2000)]... or use original version..